# Formatting a date in php. Inserting line break

Tags: php

I am using PHP to display a date and a time. Is it possible to display them with a line break in between? Or is it necessary to use the date() function twice?

I have this line of code:

```
echo date('d-M-Y \n G:i', strtotime($thread[$i]['time']));
```

Placing \n results in a new line but the n is visible on the end of the first line.

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes. Then use `\n`

Comment: A rule of thumb, with almost all languages. single quotes ('') for char literals and double quotes ("") for strings of text

Comment: Thanks for the response. using double quotes still doesn't work. The response is a /2 at the end of the first line.

Comment: The reason n results in a two is because the month being displayed is february and n is the numeric representation of the month http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php Still none the wiser on a solution though. Thanks for comments so far!

Answer (score 3):

Escaping `<br>` is a solution. r is escaped twice because it has meaning on both date function and as CR.

```
 date('d m \<\b\\r\> Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I thought this might help someone.  I had the same issue that the op was having.  I found that using the [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function provided by php in combination with `\n` fixed the problem when nothing else seemed to.

### Example:

```
nl2br(date("m/d/Y \n h:i:s A", $timestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly user double quotes to enter "\n"

```
"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a html line break, you have to add the element 'br'

in your string otherwise Vineet1982 is a text line break.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes

> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret
>   more escape sequences for special characters

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is now a /2 on the line though when I use double instead of single quotes though.

Comment: @jollinski - what do you mean with "/2"?

Comment: date("d-M-Y /n G:i", strtotime($thread[$i]['time'])); results in a 2 being displayed. I think it is because the \ isn't registering as an escape character so the n is now the numerical representation of the month (which in this case is feb) so a 2 is being shown. Is it possible that the date function overrides \ as an escape char? EDIT: I think I must have done something wrong before. I don't know what. Placing \n in does not result in a new line but \ DOES prevent the n from being displayed. No new line though.

Comment: @jollinski - `<?php var_dump(date("d-M-Y \n G:i", strtotime('now'))); ?>` works for me. What do you have in your variable? `<?php var_dump($thread[$i]['time']); ?>`

Comment: I pasted your code into mine and I got exactly the same as I did before. No line break. Could it be PHP versions issues? My variable contains "2013-02-16 16:36:13" fetched from a MySQL db.

Comment: Ok thanks. So you got no line break with my string. So the only mystery is why I didn't get one with your code. It might be time to put it on two lines.

Comment: @jollinski if you are writing to a file and opening it in windows you might want to try `\r\n`  - otherwise, are you using a browser? and are you confusing an actual line break with the markup for a line break: `<br/>`?